# For each row in a data frame, replace Non-NA values with the previous maximum number up to that point in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R where the first column represent a geographic location. All subsequent columns represent counts from each consecutive year from 1800-2020.

For each row, I only want Non-NA numbers to increase. So if a subsequent Non-NA value is lower than a previous one, change it to the maximum value up to that point.

For example it looks like this now:

| Location | 1800 | 1801 | 1802 | 1803 | 1804 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 3 |

I want it to look like this:

| Location | 1800 | 1801 | 1802 | 1803 | 1804 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- df   
df1[-1] <- matrixStats::rowCummaxs(as.matrix(df[-1]))
df1
  Location X1800 X1801 X1802 X1803 X1804
1        A     1     3     3     3     3
2        B     1     2     3     3     5
3        C     0     1     5     5     5
```

Comment: It seems to be changing all of the values in the data frame into NA's on my end.

Comment: @user6817734 the data you gave had no NA's. change the NA to `-inf` then after the code, change them back to NA

Comment: Excellent! This works! Is there a way to run this so that the above runs but only on Non-NA values?

Comment: In other words, can the same be done, but ONLY to non-NA values?